# Visual Studio crash during debugging Add-In application

Tags: development, visual-studio, debugging

I'm develop provided-hosted app (MVC) in SharePoint Online. I've installed Visual Studio Community 2017. Unfortunately, when I try to debug and install Add-In, Visual Studio freeze and not responding. If I set web application(MVC) project as only one startup project, everything works. When I try to debug only add-in application I have freeze. Even If I try to debug both projects (web app and Add-in app), I have the same freeze. The same problem occur with fresh Add-in instance. Build log looks like below:

> ...
>
> 3>  Install SharePoint Add-in:
>
> 3>  Uploading the SharePoint Add-in...
>
> 3>  Web.config updated with Client ID 141eecda-c722-4293-9696-5efd5bb01184
>
> 3>  Installation is in progress (00:00:01)
>
> 3>  Installation is in progress (00:00:03)
>
> 3>  Installation is in progress (00:00:05)
>
> 3>...
>
> 3>  Installation is in progress (00:04:07)
>
> (Freeze and not responding)

**Update (1/04/2018)**

I've installed Mozilla Firefox and I figured out that issue occurs when project is debugged on Chrome. I'll try to reinstall chrome and I'll see what will happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. As a workaround, I change the start action to start Internet Explorer instead of starting Firefox (which is my default browser).

Here are the steps:

1. Select the Addin project in the solution
2. show properties of the project (hit F4). Not the project properties, but the properties pane.
3. change Start Action to Internet explorer or Edge